# I cannot change the kernel on 4.4.11-v7+

Tags: kernel, driver

I have a pi 2B where I installed raspbian using noobs on 6-14-16. I have been trying to compile drivers for a wireless nic, specifically the archer T4UH. Doing this requires that the kernel be reverted to 3.12. I have tried this using both the instructions in the readme and using the rpi-update command with the git hash.what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of downgrading kernel versions, as some packages you currently have installed may require or expect a minimum kernel verison. My preffered route is to sift through [previous Raspbian images](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/) and look for one with either the exact kernel version you are looking for, or a slightly older one you can UPGRADE to 3.12.